# Unable to Upsert data in DynamoDB using WriteRequest JAVA

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a java application which is building a DynamoDB client write request as

```
WriteRequest.builder().putRequest(PutRequest.builder().item(attributeValueMap).build()).build();
```

The above request is replacing the items with same PartitionKey and SortKey instead of upserting the data into the table. Any idea what am I doing wrong or do I need a to pass any additional parameter in PutRequest ?

Comment: I'm confused about what behavior you are looking to implement. If an existing item has the same PartitionKey and SortKey then it will be replaced (it can't be inserted, as two items can't have the same PartitionKey/SortKey combo).

Comment: Ah, I see... you may not be providing all the attributes, so a replace isn't the same as an update. You might want to look at UpdateItem instead of PutItem, then. Perhaps someone can provide a full answer around that.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. So I have partial attributes coming from different request and they are overwriting each other because they are colliding on the partitionKey and sortKey. I was expecting them to be upserted into the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenter mentions, you want to use UpdateItem if you want to "patch" an item. PutItem will replace the entire item. You can read more about the differences here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.WritingData

This is a simplified code sample for how that works in Javav2 SDK.

```java
HashMap<String,AttributeValue> itemKey = new HashMap<>();
itemKey.put(key, AttributeValue.builder()
    .s(keyVal)
    .build());

HashMap<String,AttributeValueUpdate> updatedValues = new HashMap<>();
// Put your attributes/values you wish to update here. 
// Attributes you don't include won't be effected by the update
updatedValues.put(name, AttributeValueUpdate.builder()
    .value(AttributeValue.builder().s(updateVal).build())
    .action(AttributeAction.PUT)
    .build());

UpdateItemRequest request = UpdateItemRequest.builder()
    .tableName(tableName)
    .key(itemKey)
    .attributeUpdates(updatedValues)
    .build();

ddb.updateItem(request);
```